# How to skip system message "The system cannot find the path specified" in batch scripting

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have written a batch file which will get sql server named instance(mssqlserver\india) and the disk free space.
The content on file looks like this:

```
mssqlserver\India,D,20
mssqlserver\India,C,30
```

Now I have written a batch file to generate a html report based on the text file `Result.txt`. But my batch script is picking mssqlserver\India as a system location and is popping message for every entry in the text file, its moving to the next variable after I press enter key.

I want to ignore this message without any user interaction. Below is the script i am using:

```
@ECHO off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SETLOCAL
cd C:\Users
goto head >nul

:head
FOR /F "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%G IN (Result.txt) DO (
%%G%%H%%I
set temphost1=%%G
set temphost2=%%H
set temphost3=%%I
call :stripquotes %temphost1% %temphost2% %temphost3% >NUL
)
goto :end
:stripquotes
echo ^<tr bgcolor="#90EE90"^>^<td^>^%temphost1%^</td^>^<td^>^%temphost2%^</td^>^<td^>^%temphost3%^</td^>^</tr^>^ >> C:\Users\Report.html
:END
CLS
ECHO COMPLETED
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

With some `@rem` commented changes, next script could work:

```
@ECHO off
@rem EnableDelayedExpansion not applied in the code
@rem use enableextensions in the next line
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@rem superabundant SETLOCAL
cd C:\Users
@rem Why "goto head >nul" as GOTO does not produce any output?
@rem And why next   "goto head"  at all? 
goto head >nul

:head
FOR /F "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%G IN (Result.txt) DO (
    @rem this caused the error message %%G%%H%%I
    set temphost1=%%G
    set temphost2=%%H
    set temphost3=%%I
    call :stripquotes 
    @rem this were superabundant and harmful %temphost1% %temphost2% %temphost3% >NUL
)
goto :end

:stripquotes
@rem some superfluous `^` carets removed from next line but the last one was harmful
echo ^<tr bgcolor="#90EE90"^>^<td^>%temphost1%^</td^>^<td^>%temphost2%^</td^>^<td^>%temphost3%^</td^>^</tr^> >> C:\Users\Report.html
@rem next line to return from the :stripquotes subroutine 
goto :eof

:END
CLS
ECHO COMPLETED
PAUSE
```